# отключение регулярных выражений pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Всем добрый день! Парсю df - дело в том, что нужно отключить регулярные выражения. К примеру, есть слова с `"."` и их необходимо обработать именно с точкой - с точки зрения регулярных выражений все работает супер но нужно их отключить! `.extract` не содержит `regex`
плюс вставил `r` везде где возможно!
Думаю, дело в этом элементе кода:

```
df_word_1 = pd.read_excel(words_df, r'word_1', engine='openpyxl')

df[r'first_word'] = df[r"last_word"].str.extract('(' +'|'.join(list(df_word_1[r"Слово_код"])) + ')')
```

Comment: почему вы решили, что у вас эти "слова с точкой" неверно обрабатываются?

Comment: Они обрабатываются верно в контексте регулярных выражений! Но нужно что бы программа обрабатывала их "как есть" к примеру сейас слова "привет" и "п.ивет" обработаются одинаково (программа их найдет по слову "п.ивет") но для конечного пользователя регулярные выражения не подходят... и в extract нет regex... странно что "r" не работает во время чтения!

Comment: Погодите, но вы же именно регулярку там и "сочиняете", соединяя слова через `|`, вы хотите использовать регулярку. Вам видимо просто нужно экранировать сами точки в словах, что-то типа `df_word_1["Слово_код"].str.replace('.', r'\.')`

Comment: @CrazyElf Да разобрался! Спасибо! Проблема была в экранировании! Но Ваш код я как раз по какой то пока не ведомой причине я много раз пробывал и именно сейчас он не сработал! попробую найти причину почему! И по моему уже нашёл! сеичас проведу пару тестов и отпишусь! В любом случаем спасибо!!!!

Comment: Если что этот код вместо `df_word_1[r"Слово_код"]` надо подставить. Но вообще я мог и ошибиться где-то )

Comment: @CrazyElf проблема была в этом `df_word_1["Слово_код"].str.replace(r'\.' r'\.')` - пока что не понимаю почему но это помогло! + метод `replace` я добавил внутрь метода `str.extract`